# Bot Framework C#, Add a numpad

Tags: c#, botframework

I have these numbers and a send button as a suggested action. As we all know if we click one of these numbers it will send directly and go to the next waterfall step.

[image]

How to make it like a numpad like if I click number 2 it will just display in the sendbox until tapping the Send button?

```
        public async Task<DialogTurnResult> StartConversation(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var choices = new[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Send"};
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("NumPad", new PromptOptions
            {
                Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(choices),

            }, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use case here. Is this for a mobile app? Are we to assume you're using Web Chat?

Comment: Yea2, sorry I'm using the ReactWebChat.

Comment: Okay but in what situation is it better to use your numpad than the device's numpad? What kind of device is this meant to be run on?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hello @KyleDelaney, Yea2 right now I'm implementing it through ReactWebChat. I'm catching it by its type. I changed the type from suggested action to herocard. So that if the herocard type is loaded the numpad will fire-up. I don't know if it's the best. But it's working. The problem with this one is if I have more than 1 hero card.

Comment: Are you saying you've resolved this issue?

Comment: Yea2, I should close this one.

Comment: You can post an answer and accept it if you like